# Back button will bring to home page after firebase logout on app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, logout

My issue is very similar to this post: ([When I press back button on login page it will go to main menu (after I select yes for logout in MainMenu activity)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586925/when-i-press-back-button-on-login-page-it-will-go-to-main-menu-after-i-select-y)).

Basically, even after I select "YES" option to logout, it does bring me back to the indented page (Login page). However, when I press the back button on my actual phone (S7 Edge+) and 2 emulators (Nexus 4 & Pixel 2 XL), it bring me to the dashboard page again which it should not be that way.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED was I added finish() to Logout function and in the menu as seen below:

**Logout function/method**

```
private void Logout(){
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

**Menu**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.logoutMenu: {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to logout?");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "You are succesfully signed out!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Logout();
                    finish();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.profileMenu: {
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, UpdateProfileActivity.class));
            break;
        }
        case R.id.passwordMenu: {
            startActivity(new Intent(SecondActivity.this, UpdatePasswordActivity.class));
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The issue still persist. There is no error found in logcat though so I am not sure how to overcome this issue?

Does anyone have a solution? Please do guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: When you press logout just add clear top flag and call `finishAffinity()` instead of `finish()` which will finish your all previous activities.

Comment: Try using [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11472684/5990846)

Comment: @Piyush finishAffinity() did it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jay Very useful! Thank you!

Comment: Check also **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885891/one-time-login-in-app-firebaseauth)** out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private void Logout(){
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**Just try this **

Comment: Hi thanks for your response! I have tried and I'm having all the intent error (Cannot resolve symbol 'intent'). I believe your solution is similar to Jay and so I will still give you an upvote as they are useful! Many thanks :>

Answer (score 1):

So the actual solution worked for the author is using `finishAffinity()` but not the accepted answer. Which worked for me too.